# Etymologie von "verwordakelt"; was bedeutet "teigeln"?

Tags: etymology, dialect, austrian

Heute brachte meine Frau frisches Gebäck vom Bäcker nach Hause, und als sie das Sackerl aufgemacht und zwei Mohnflesserl und zwei Kaisersemmeln auf den Teller gelegt hat, sagte sie über die Semmeln:

> Des san Handsemmeln, drum schaun die so **verwordakelt** aus.

Das ist Wiener Dialekt (meine Frau ist gebürtige Wienerin), die standarddeutsche Übersetzung lautet:

> Das sind händisch hergestellte Semmeln, daher sehen sie so **verformt/unförmig/missgestaltet** aus.

Ich bin in der Steiermark aufgewachsen, und auch dort ist *»verwordakelt«* ein häufig verwendetes Wort der Alltagssprache. Etwas wird als *verwordakelt* bezeichnet, wenn es zwar auffällig unförmig, aber dennoch liebenswert und sympatisch ist. Laut [ostarrichi.org](https://www.ostarrichi.org/wort/5719/verwordagelt_verwordakelt) kennen 87% aller Besucher der Seite dieses Wort. Es steht in [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verwordakelt) und ist dort (völlig zurecht) als "mundartlich" gekennzeichnet, weswegen es auch in den fast allen Wörterbüchern des Standarddeutschen fehlt. (Leider. Ich liebe dieses Wort, denn ich kenne sonst kein anderes Wort, das ein äußerliches Gestaltdefizit mit Liebenswürdigkeit vereint.) In meiner Ausgabe des ÖWB (österreichisches Wörterbuch, das amtliche Regelwerk für österreichisches Deutsch) findet man das Wort auf Seite 630 (39. Auflage von 2001), ebenfalls mit dem Vermerk "mda." (=mundartlich), in zwei alternativen Schreibweisen: *»verwordagelt«* und *»verwordakel«* (in weiten Teilen Österreichs gibt es kaum einen Unterschied in der Aussprache von *»g«* und *»k«* (ebenso d/t und b/p)). Im DWDS gibt es gerade mal [3 Einträge im Korpus](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=public&q=verwordakelt), was ebenfalls klar belegt, dass es kein standarddeutsches Wort ist, sondern ein Dialektwort.

Mich interessiert aber die Etymologie dieses Worts. Was ist sein Ursprung? Gerade bei Dialektwörtern ist das ofmals extrem schwer herauszufinden.

In dem [Wiktionary-Eintrag](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verwordakelt) steht:

> **Herkunft:**
> möglicherweise von mittelhochdeutsch verwohrt (= verwirkt) und teigeln

[Sprachnudel.de](https://www.sprachnudel.de/woerterbuch/verwordakelt) zitiert diesen Satz wortwörtlich aus Wiktionary (Oder ist es umgekehrt? Jedenfalls steht auf beiden Seiten exakt dasselbe.) Andere Hinweise auf die Herkunft habe ich nicht gefunden. Wie erwartet schweigt sich darüber auch mein Duden-Herkunftswörterbuch aus.

Mit dem Hinweis *»mittelhochdeutsch verwohrt (= verwirkt)«* kann ich ja noch etwas anfangen, aber das Wort *»teigeln«* (ich vermute, dass es sich dabei um ein Verb handelt) kenne ich nicht und ich kann auch nirgendwo Hinweise auf seine Existenz geschweige denn auf seine Bedeutung finden. Ist es mit *»deichseln«* (etwas durch Geschick zustande bringen) verwandt? Die [Etymologie von *»deichseln«* auf DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/deichseln#etymwb-1) spricht eher dagegen. Eine Verwandtschaft mit dem Substantiv *»Teig«* schließe ich auch eher aus.

Comment: "Wort, das ein äußerliches Gestaltdefizit mit Liebenswürdigkeit vereint" – mir fällt dafür das vor allem in Rheinhessen verbreitete _Knorz_ ein, dass, wenn schon nicht eine liebenswürdige, so doch zumindest eine faszinierend vertrehte Form (einer Baum- oder Rebwurzel) bezeichnet. Neben der Bezeichnung _knorzig_ für ein faltiges Gesicht gibt es übrigens auch _Knorzen_ für ein Brot/Brötchen mit unregelmäßig aufgebrochener Oberfläche ([Beispiel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinknorzen)).

Comment: Bayerisches Wörterbuch (Bayerische Akademie der Wissenschaften) kennt *verwordakelt* noch nicht, wohl aber *verwerktageln*, *bei dem wird alles gleich verwerktaglt* „er zieht seine neuen Kleider schon bald an Werktagen an“ sowie *verwartäckeln* "verunstalten, verderben", die bald dieselbe Bedeutung haben. Schrecklich unergonomisch die BAdW Seite, BDO auch nicht viel besser.

Comment: Aus dem Bayerischen kenne ich das Wort "verhunaglt" oder "verhunackelt". Vgl. [hier]}(https://www.niederbayern-wiki.de/wiki/Verhunagln). Vielleicht kein Synonym für "verwordakelt", aber doch sehr ähnlich im Gebrauch und im Klang. Zu "teigeln" vgl. [hier](https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/index#29566).

Comment: @PaulFrost: Die Bedeutungen der Wörter *»verwoadakelt«* und *»verhunaglt«* (welches mir bis dato unbekannt war) sind sehr ähnlich, daher sind sie partielle Synonyme (Homöonyme). Das sagt aber nichts über ihre Etymologie aus (Die Wörter *»Aufzug«, »Fahrstuhl«* und *»Lift«* sind auch Synonyme, ohne dass jemand eine gemeinsame etymologische Wurzel konstruieren wollen würde.) Ich kann außer derselben Silbenanzahl auch keinerlei Ähnlichkeit im Klang erkennen. Ich nehme zwischen *»verwackelt«* und *»verwoadakelt«* eine deutlich größere Ähnlichkeit war.

Answer (score 2):

Das Verb "teigeln" gibt es jedenfalls [in bayerischen Dialekten](https://bdo.badw.de/suche?lemma=teigeln&options%5Bexact%5D=1&options%5Bcase%5D=1#bwb__teigeln1). Einige der verschiedenen Bedeutungen haben tatsächlich etwas mit Teig zu tun, nämlich "einen Teig zubereiten, einen Teig kneten" oder auch "nach Teig oder allgemein unangenehm riechen". Weitere Bedeutungen sind beispielsweise "weich werden" oder "sich einschmeicheln".

Was die Verbindung zu "verwordakelt" betrifft, dürften zwei Bedeutungsvarianten interessant sein:

"Mit weicher Masse herumschmieren, mit Teig herumspielen" kann schon mal ein weniger ansehnliches Resultat haben.

"Empfindlich sein, schwächlich sein" lässt mich an den früher oft vermuteten Zusammenhang zwischen äußerlicher Missgestalt und Schwäche, schwacher Konstitution o. ä. denken.

Comment: Die Bedeutung "Teig kneten" finde auch interessant, dann könnte sich "verwordagelt" vielleicht von sowas wie "verwohrt geknetet" (schlecht/falsch geknetet) ableiten.

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke das Wort verwoataglt, verwordaklt, oder verwortaglt stammt von den Wörtern verworren und getakelt ab. Außerdem findet sich die Takelage ja auch zweckentfremdet wieder, wenn sich Menschen herrausputzen. Heute bist du aber aufgetakelt. Heute hast du dich ganz schön aufgetakelt. aufgetaglt, aufgedaklt. Ein Segelboot auftakeln.
Die Takelage besteht aus stehendem (Mast, Baum,...) und laufendem Gut (Seile).
eventuell hochdeutsch, verworrtakelt oder verwortakelt?

Comment: In der Alpenregion und an der Donau (die ja auch nicht grade für Hochseeschifffahrt bekannt ist) dürfte das Wort "Takelage" jetzt eher nicht so gängig sein....

Comment: Das Wort *»verwordakelt«* wird in Ost-Österreich verwendet. Österreich ist aber ein Binnenland. Österreich hatte zu Zeiten der Habsburger-Monarchie zwar einen Zugang zum Meer und sogar eine Marine (immerhin hat ein Österreicher die Schiffsschraube erfunden), aber in diesem Küstengebiet wurde nicht Deutsch gesprochen, sondern in einem kleinen Teil Italienisch (Triest gehörte zu Österreich) und slawische Sprachen (in Gebieten, die heute zu Slowenien und Kroatien gehören). Die Takelage hat es daher im deutschsprachigen Teil Österreichs nicht in den allgemeinen Wortschatz geschafft. Das ...

Comment: ... Verb *»sich auftakeln«* wurde zwar auch in Österreich benutzt, aber nur mit der Bedeutung, sich auffallend grell zu schminken, auffallenden Schmuck und eine auffallende Frisur zu tragen. Man drückt damit aus, dass die betreffende Person sich bemühte, sich besonders schön zu machen, dieses Ziel aber deutlich verfehlte. Wenn man aber zu einer unförmigen Semmel sagt, sie sei verwordakelt, will man damit keineswegs aussagen, das versucht wurde, die Semmel möglichst schön zu gestalten. Sie ist einfach nur unförmig geworden. Die Semmel ist schiach, aber erscheint trotzdem sympatisch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: "aufgetakelt" kenne ich nur aus der Standardsprache, in ostösterreichischen Dialekten werden meines Wissens andere Vergleiche/Topen bemüht, etwa *aufputzt wia a Christbaam/Maibaam*. *wia a frisch lackierts Hutschpferd* oder dergleichen.

Comment: @bakunin: Das muss ich widersprechen. Der Ausdruck *»auftaklte oide Schochtl«* kann im Osten Österreichs durchaus als abwertende Bezeichnung einer älteren Dame verwendet werden, die es mit Schmuck und Schminke wieder mal maßlos übertrieben hat. Aber selbst, wenn du Recht hättest, würde das per se nicht ausschließen, dass *»auftakeln«* die Wurzel von *»verwordakelt«* sein könnte. Das Wort *A* könnte in der Vergangenheit gängig gewesen sein, könnte mit ...

Comment: ... einem Präfix zu *B* abgewandelt worden sein, dann ist *A* verschwunden, *B* wurde weiter abgewandelt und existiert heute weiter als *B'.* Beispiel: Das Verb *»erkiesen«* (*»Johann erkiest Roswita zu seiner Frau.«*) war im 18. Jahrhundert noch in alle seinen Formen gängig, ist inzwischen aber im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum ausgestorben. Und obwohl es heute nicht mehr existiert, ist es trotzdem die Wurzel des partizipalen Adjektivs *»auserkoren«.* (*»Die vom Showmaster auserkorene Dame betrat die Bühne.«*)

Comment: Ich habe nicht gesagt, daß "verworda(g/k)elt" nicht von "Takelage" kommen kann, ich habe lediglich die Häufigkeit des Wortes "aufgetakelt" in ost-österreichischen Dialekten bezweifelt. Das Wort "erkiesen" wird zwar in seinen meisten Formen nicht mehr benutzt, das von Dir genannte Partizip und das Präteritum aktiv ("die Glücksgötting erkor ihn zu ihrem Favoriten" = "er gewann, aber mit mehr Glück als Verstand") jedoch durchaus.