# Warum sind manche Dialektwörter Bestandteile einer Standardvariation, andere aber nicht?

Tags: usage, standard-german, dialect, austrian

Ich habe gerade eine Frage über das Adjektiv [verwordakelt](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/75281/1487) gestellt, und im Zuge dessen fiel mir auf, dass es im Osten Österreichs sehr viele bairische Vokabeln gibt, die dort in den regionalen Dialekten höchstlebendig sind und mit relativ hoher Frequenz verwendet werden, und die man auch in der Alltagssprache häufig antrifft, ohne dass irgendjemand auf die Idee käme, diese Wörter in einem Kontext zu verwenden, der Hochdeutsch (im Sinn von: Standarddeutsch) verlangt.

Beispiele dafür sind:

> **verwordakelt** = deformiert, aber trotzdem liebenswert
> **schiach** = unschön, hässlich
> **rean** = weinen *(dazu habe ich auch mal [eine Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/58367/1487) gestellt)*
> sich **vergogeln** = sich irren
> **Recherl** = Pfifferling
> **urassen** = etwas vergeuden, mit etwas verschwenderisch umgehen
> ...

Diese Wörter werden in einem Gebiet mit mehreren Millionen Einwohnern relativ häufig in der Alltagssprache verwendet, gelten aber als strikt zu einem Dialekt gehörend.

Die nächsten Beispiele werden in der Alltagssprache mit ähnlicher Häufigkeit verwendet, sind aber amtlich bescheinigt höchstoffizieller Bestandteil der deutschen Standardsprache (Auszug aus dem österreichischen [EU-Beitrittsvertrag - Akte - Protokoll Nr. 10](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/NormDokument.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=10007687&FassungVom=2021-03-10&Artikel=&Paragraf=&Anlage=1&Uebergangsrecht=)):

> **Eierschwammerl** = Pfifferling
> **Fisolen** = grüne Bohnen
> **Karfiol** = Blumenkohl
> **Kren** = Meerrettich
> **Ribisel** = Johannisbeeren
> **Topfen** = Quark

Dass in diesem speziellen Dokument ausschließlich Namen von Lebensmitteln enthalten sind, die mit genau diesen Namen in Österreich produziert und verkauft werden, ist kein Wunder. Da steckte zur Zeit des österreichischen EU-Beitritts die begründete Angst dahinter, man müsse nach dem EU-Beitritt z.B. auf die Topfen-Packerln das Wort *»Quark«* drucken um sie weiterhin in Österreich verkaufen zu dürfen, was (zumindest im Fall von Topfen/Quark) bis heute so gut wie alle Österreicher mit großer Vehemenz ablehnen würden.

Aber es gibt auch viele andere Wörter, die nicht durch amtliche Dokumente geadelt wurden und nur in Österreich zum Standarddeutsch gehören:

> **Trafik** = Verkaufsstelle für Zigaretten, Zeitungen und Zeitschriften ([Bild einer Trafik](https://media.tourdata.at/display/responsiveDetailImg/aa4a095b77cf536a2849e9ee9f016c4b.jpg))
> **Wimmerl** = Pustel, Pickel ([Quelle 1](https://www.miss.at/so-drueckst-du-deine-wimmerl-richtig-aus/), [Quelle 2](https://www.medizinpopulaer.at/2014/kosmetik-pflege/wieder-ein-wimmerl/), [Quelle 3](https://www.meinbezirk.at/innere-stadt/c-gesundheit/wimmerl-bloss-nicht-ausdruecken_a4442811))
> **sudern** = jammern, nörgeln ([Quelle 1](https://www.derstandard.at/story/2000132415405/wie-ehrlich-kann-man-mit-freundinnen-und-freunden-sein), [Quelle 2](https://www.krone.at/2901522), [Quelle 3](https://www.vienna.at/rauchergesetz-nichtraucher-lobby-sudert-wk-jubelt/3139890))
> **spengeln** = Blech bearbeiten ([Quelle 1](https://www.koglermartin.com/images/Autos/slides/NSU_3.html), [Quelle 2](https://www.stainz.at/tourismus-freizeit/museen-in-stainz/traktormuseum), [Quelle 3](https://www.leichtfried.co.at/leistungen/spenglerei))
> **pölzen** = Bauwerk seitlich abstützen ([Quelle 1](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Dokument.wxe?Abfrage=Vwgh&Dokumentnummer=JWT_1994020388_19941223X00), [Quelle 2](https://www.wohnnet.at/bauen/rohbau/kuenetten-43291), [Quelle 3](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Dokumente/Landesnormen/LBG12001725/LBG12001725.html))
> ...

Einige dieser Wörter wird man auch in Bayern hören, dort gelten sie aber nicht als Bestandteil der Standardsprache, sondern werden höchstens als Teil der Alltagssprache wahrgenommen, eher noch gelten sie dort als Dialektwörter.

Ich frage mich nun, was der Grund dafür sein könnte, dass einige Wörter (darunter alle aus meiner ersten Liste) auch in Österreich so unzweifelhaft als Dialektwörter wahrgenommen werden, während viele andere Wörter als standardsprachlich empfunden und verwendet werden (darunter alle aus meinen beiden anderen Aufzählungen). Ist das wirklich nur Zufall, oder stecken da vielleicht irgendwelche Lautmuster dahinter?

Answer (score 3):

Kurze Antwort: Zufall.

Viele Wörter haben einen regionalen Ursprung. Welches Wort sich überregional durchsetzt, lässt sich im Einzelfall nicht vorhersehen. Das südliche «Samstag» verdrängt das nördliche «Sonnabend», das nördliche «Treppe» verdrängt das südliche «Stiege» – wobei letzteres in einer Spezialbedeutung weiterexistieren kann, nämlich als Bezeichnung für die steilen Holztreppen, wie sie etwa in alten Bauernhäusern zu finden sind.

Am ehesten dürfte es wohl Tendenzen für bestimmte semantische Felder geben. Lebensmittel haben wohl besonders oft regionale Bedeutungen. Begriffe der Seefahrt kommen eher aus dem Norden (sogar das Wort «Süden» ist nordseegermanisch).

Comment: Die Stiege wurde in Österreich noch nicht von der Treppe verdrängt: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/34440/1487

Answer (score 1):

Es könnte sein, dass Kochbücher über die Wiener Küche, die weit über Österreich hinaus gelesen und benutzt wurden, größere Bekanntheit erlangt haben und dass es für das Marketing sogar förderlich ist, wenn die Leute in einem Anhang hinten nachschlagen müssen, was denn nun Karfiol oder Topfen ist, weil es den Rezepten eine höhere Authentizität verleiht.

Hinzu könnte getreten sein, dass, nachdem sie es gedruckt gelesen haben, die Verwender des Wortes dieses mit mehr Selbstbewusstsein, mit mehr Selbstverständlichkeit verwendet haben, auch in Situationen wie Gastronomie und Tourismus, wo mit vielen Nachfragen dann umgegangen werden muss.

Das Kriterium für Dialekt müsste aber m.M. nach sein, ob das Wort in Tirol und Wien so verwendet wird - dann ist es Österreichs Hochdeutsch. Wenn nicht, dann ist es ein Dialekt.

Comment: Der Begriff [Hochdeutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochdeutsch) ist mehrdeutig. Damit bezeichnet man auch alle Dialekte, die südlich der Benrather Linie gesprochen werden, und dort liegen Österreich, die Schweiz, ganz Bayern, ganz Ba-Wü und Teile angrenzender deutscher Bundesländer. Du meinst vermutlich "österreichisches Standarddeutsch". Das ist aber eine genormte Sprache, die durch Schulbücher, Gesetzestexte und nationale Medien innerhalb der politischen Grenzen des Staates Österreich verbreitet wird und daher per Definition sowohl in Tirol als auch in Wien und auch ...

Comment: ... in Vorarlberg, nicht aber z.B. in München verwendet wird. In Tirol spricht man südbairische (=alpenbairische) Dialekte, in Wien, Salzburg und München mittelbairische (=donaubairische) Dialekte.

Comment: In Tirol sagt niemand "Fleischhauer" sondern "Metzger", in Wien ist es genau umgekehrt. Da keines der beiden Wörter im jeweils anderen Gebiet in der Alltagssprache verwendet wird, müssten beide nach deiner Definition Dialektwörter sein. In den österreichischen Gesetzen ([Beispiel](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/GeltendeFassung.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=10004374)) und Schulbüchern kommt aber nur der Fleischhauer vor, daher ist dieses Wort Standarddeutsch in Österreich. (Beim Wort "Metzger" steht im ÖWB: "*(westöst., D): Fleischhauer*")